# Java - Existing console application - Create Web application

Tags: java, web-development, netbeans

I have a 'background' application which gathers certain data and performs certain actions over time. This application has been created in Netbeans (SE) as a regular Java application. One of my controller classes has an overview of everything which recently happened.

Now I'm in need of a website that will allow me to view the recent events and set certain flags in the running application. I wanted to create the website for my smartphone with Spring. So I upgraded my Netbeans to the EE version to have access to the features.

I created this web application in a separate Netbeans project and then wanted to "import" the project into the original application. So when I launch the background application, this will also trigger the Spring application to run (binding to port 80/8080). But this seems to be more tricky then I thought. Because I want to avoid communicating via RPC's or web services. I'd rather keep everything in memory, and avoid having to convert objects to XML, SQL records or similar.

Are there any (lightweight) frameworks or software kits out there that will allow me to start a webserver and easily communicate data with it (in memory)?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, Sir Troll! This site is about recommending software *products*, not algorithms, services, or designs – so sorry to tell you, but your question is off-topic here as we don't "deliver howtos". You might wish to check the `/help/on-topic` page of one of the SE developers stacks such as [SO] and "programming", it *may* fit there (I'm not active on any of them, so I'm not sure). Good luck nevertheless!

Comment: @Izzy I'm looking for frameworks or software implementations which will allow me to start a webserver from a java application. Perhaps it wasn't specified to clearly in my post. But the solution can be web server "software"/"framework". Not restricted to Java or Netbeans.

Comment: Then I'd recommend to [edit] your question. Currently it rather reads like "how could I approach my problem" rather than "which software fulfils my requirements". For more guidance, you might wish to check with [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). Be also welcome in chat, we're ready to help you out :)